# Stuck when ordering parallel vectors C

Tags: sorting

What I need to do, is read N (the number of next inputs) and then it will follow the pattern: (name) (age) (height) What I need to do is print 2 lists. One in a crescent order of the ages, by printing names, and then by height. An example would be:

```
2
Carol, 33 1.85
Peter, 21 1.92
```

output:

```
By age: Peter, Carol
By hight: Carol, Peter
```

For now, im not worried about the output exact format or copying the same ordering "function", I'm just trying to make the first one work, so then I can just copypaste for the height. Im also not really worried about optimization, I'm just trying to focus on what I'm doing wrong here. 
This is what I've got so far:

```
        int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char nomes[30][50], age_ord[30][50], alt_ord[30][50], aux[50];
    int idade[30], n, i, j=1, aux2;
    double altura[30];
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%s %d %lf", nomes[i], &idade[i], &altura[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n; i++){
        strcpy(age_ord[i], nomes[i]);
        strcpy(alt_ord[i], nomes[i]);
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){      // ordenador de idade
        j=1;
        for(;i+j<=n;j++){
            if(idade[i] > idade[i+j]){
                strcpy(aux, nomes[i+j]);
                strcpy(nomes[i+j], age_ord[i]);
                strcpy(age_ord[i], aux);
                aux2 = idade[i];
                idade[i] = idade[i+j];
                idade[i+j] = aux2;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Por idade: ");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%s, ", age_ord[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the best thing to do in these cases is simply the code.  I've augmented your data, to better stress the sort code, and dropped the commas:

```
3
Carol 33 1.85
Peter 21 1.92
Claude 29 1.89
```

First, you don't need to be copying strings during your sort. You can shuffle pointers or indexes -- below I use indexes.  I've only reworked it for age -- I'll let your copy & paste for height as you suggest:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char nomes[30][50];
    int idade[30];
    double altura[30];

    int n, aux, age_ord[30], alt_ord[30];

    // read N (the number of next inputs)
    scanf("%d", &n);

    // then it will follow the pattern: (name) (age) (height) 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%s %d %lf", nomes[i], &idade[i], &altura[i]);

        age_ord[i] = alt_ord[i] = i; // initialize unsorted
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
            if (idade[age_ord[j]] > idade[age_ord[j + 1]]) {
                aux = age_ord[j];
                age_ord[j] = age_ord[j + 1];
                age_ord[j + 1] = aux;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Por idade: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s ", nomes[age_ord[i]]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Once we have the sorted array of indexes, to get the output, we simply use those sorted indexes to access the array of names.  This code outputs:

```
Por idade: Peter Claude Carol
```

You can use the same nested pair of loops for the height sorting, you don't need to copy it all, just add the `if` statement for height after the one for age.

Comment: Well, it doest work but seems like theres alot of concepts there that I didnt go through yet. Gonna work on trying to understand whats going on there, thanks for that! But if its not too much to ask, if you could atleast point out a way to fix what i've done? That would also be a great lesson for me. Thanks again!

Comment: Works fine for me.  I tossed the commas in your example data, e.g. "Carol 33 1.85" and added a third person to really check the sorting, "Claude 29 1.89"  (Bump N to 3)  The output I get is "Peter Claude Carol" for age and "Carol Claude Peter" for height.  What isn't working for you?

Comment: @Jubilu, I've augmented my answer to include a fix of your original sort.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi , I think there is something wrong in your sort algorithm.

```
Pls Try this segment code:
for(i=0; i<n; i++){      // ordenador de idade
    j=1;
    for(;i+j<n;j++){
```

> 